# Laravel: How to push an object into a variable and return?

Tags: laravel, collections, push

I'm trying to return direct children from a given node of this left-right tree:

[image: left-right tree]

This is the code I have in the model:

```
    public function scopeHijos($query, $categoria_id){
        $categoria = Categoria::find($categoria_id);
        echo $izq = $categoria->izquierda;
        echo $der = $categoria->derecha;
        $izq++;
        echo $izq;
        if ($izq<$der) {
            do {
                $hijo = Categoria::where('izquierda', $izq)
                    ->take(1)
                    ->get();
                foreach ($hijo as $hijo) {
                    //$hijos->push($hijo);
                    $i = ($hijo->derecha)+1;
                }
                $izq=$i;
            } while ( $izq<$der);
        }

        //return $hijos;
    }
}
```

The problem is in $hijos->push($hijo). I cannot find a way to push the query result into $hijos var in order to return it. How can it be done?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simpler answer: Adding a 'parent' field to the table and creating a self relation in the Category model.